# find table with most rows in entire sql 2016 instance

Tags: sql-server-2016

I was trying to solve this specific issue:

I needed a single query that will retrieve the table in the entire instance with most rows. (I would run it in 20 sql instances, all sql 2016.)

It would be run in production so; ideally, it should not be a resource-consuming SP…

All other solutions I saw were… either for sql 2005, or they just retrieved it for a single database.

Comment: Can you link to the solutions you saw for SQL Server 2005, and tell us why they are insufficient for you?

Comment: I used https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/batuhanyildiz/2013/01/17/top-n-biggest-tables-in-every-database/ but it takes more than 3 mintues to run it, so I killed it...

Comment: That is for size, not number of rows AFAICT.

Comment: So do you really need the table with the most rows, or the largest in size?